# SQL Server distinct select latest date only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, distinct

So I have a distinct query and can narrow my list to what I am after, but there are occasions where the last table may have 3 correct selections and I only want the latest occurrence.

Current query:

```
SELECT DISTCINT
    D.Filename, S.Name AS State, W.Name AS 'Workflow Name', U.Username AS 'Name', 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, TH.Date, 101) AS [Entered State], 
    DATEDIFF(dd, TH.Date, GETUTCDATE()) AS [Days In State]
FROM
    Status AS S 
INNER JOIN
    Documents AS D ON D.CurrentStatusID = S.StatusID 
INNER JOIN
    Workflows AS W ON W.WorkflowID = S.WorkflowID 
INNER JOIN 
    TransitionHistory AS TH ON D.DocumentID = TH.DocumentID 
                            AND D.LatestRevisionNo - 1 = TH.RevNr 
INNER JOIN
    Users AS U ON U.UserID = TH.UserID
WHERE
    d.Filename NOT LIKE '%test%' 
    AND d.filename NOT LIKE '%^%' 
    AND S.Name IN ('Initiated', 'Design Review', 'Change Pending Approval',
                   'Under Editing', 'Waiting for Approval', 'Under Change',
                   'ECO Design Review', 'Minor Change no Revision',)
    AND W.Name IN ('Production')
ORDER BY
    Filename
```

As an example if I pick a specific file (see image) you can see the results:

[image]

You can see in the last table the results produce 3 rows that meet the criteria, I am trying to find an easy way to have it match all my criteria and then only output the highest TransitionNr or the latest date.

I am not a SQL person, I have put this together from google searches - but I just cannot seem to find the final piece.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: please provide sample data and expected results - i suspect you will need to partition here and filter only the top one

Comment: If you dont even care about group the results you might use..
`SELECT * FROM TransitionHistory WHEREDocumentID = 54666 andRevNr = 1 GROUP BY DocumentID ` , or add other condition on your where to pick the one you want

Comment: Sorry, the data tables are all quite large, my current output is over 10k rows. The image is simply showing a sample of a specific query which I was using to find out why my results contained duplicates when I was using a select distinct.

Comment: Your image doesn't seem to have anything to do with the query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution would be:

```
SELECT D.Filename, S.Name AS STATE, W.Name AS 'Workflow Name', U.Username AS 'Name',
CONVERT(VARCHAR, MAX(TH.DATE), 101) AS [Entered State],
DATEDIFF(dd, MAX(TH.DATE), GETUTCDATE()) AS [Days In State]
FROM STATUS S
INNER JOIN Documents D ON D.CurrentStatusID = S.StatusID
INNER JOIN Workflows W ON W.WorkflowID = S.WorkflowID
INNER JOIN TransitionHistory TH ON (D.DocumentID = TH.DocumentID AND D.LatestRevisionNo - 1 = TH.RevNr)
INNER JOIN Users AS U ON U.UserID = TH.UserID
WHERE d.Filename NOT LIKE '%test%'
AND d.filename NOT LIKE '%^%'
AND S.Name IN ('Initiated', 'Design Review', 'Change Pending Approval', 'Under Editing', 'Waiting for Approval', 'Under Change', 'ECO Design Review', 'Minor Change no Revision')
AND W.Name IN ('Production')
GROUP BY D.Filename, S.Name, W.Name, U.Username
```

Comment: kbbal That produced very similar results as my original - which I find odd since you used the max date. I still end up with duplicates, although not quite as many. My original query produced 10,490 rows - where yours produced 9,687.

Comment: However, it turns out it is a data fault from the setup of the original database. kbball you got it.

Answer (score 1):

try replacing all references to `TH.Date` with `MAX(TH.Date)` in your query.

Comment: That gave me an error. I need it to give me most recent TH.Date, not max

Comment: @demarcjp max date should give the the most recent date as it should return the value which is greatest which would be the most recent date

Comment: @kbbal has it correct. With the appropriate group by statement at the end.